# Is it possible to generate a MYSQL query of more tables with values of one table column as more query columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have more tables, which I want to combine together for generate a CSV file what our backoffice system can read.
I have 1 table with Product information and an other table with language information. The databases are build up as the following example:

Product database:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td><td>productnumber</td><td>price</td><td>name_id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>ABC123</td><td>10.00</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td><td>DEF456</td><td>15.00</td><td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Name database:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td><td>name_id</td><td>name</td><td>language_id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>Cheese</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td><td>1</td><td>Fromagi</td><td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td><td>1</td><td>Kase</td><td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td><td>2</td><td>Water</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td><td>2</td><td>Acqua</td><td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td><td>2</td><td>Wasser</td><td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Language database:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td><td>Language</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td><td>Italian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td><td>German</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to have as output for the CSV file is like this:
Productnumber + Price + Name_EN + Name_IT + Name_DE

So:
ABC123 | 10.00 | Cheese | Fromagi | Kase
DEF456 | 15.00 | Water .  | Acqua . . | Wasser

Is there a way how to achieve this?

If you need more information, just let me know!
Thank you all in advance.
Best regards,
Koen de Haan

Comment: I think you just want to join the table together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the name table multiple times with the Product table.

```
select p.id, p.productnumber, p.price, en.name, it.name, de.name
from Product p
  join Name en on en.name_id=p.name_id and en.language_id=1
  join Name it on it.name_id=p.name_id and it.language_id=2
  join Name de on de.name_id=p.name_id and de.language_id=3
```

For the future, it is better to show the actual table create script rather than some HTML code.

Comment: This one does the trick! The next time I'll add the table create script. Actually my database is a lot more complex, for that I gave an easy example, so I can figure it out how the basics worked. Anyway, I got it working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

on my vision , you can create temporary table using a stored procedure and inject the resault into a file :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getyourstuff()
BEGIN

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_stuff;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_stuff 
    SELECT your,sweet,request  from your database;

    -- write the into file ....
    SELECT * 
      INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/mystufffile.txt'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
      FROM tmp_stuff;

    -- if you wanna display the resault , if not remove the line below 
    SELECT * FROM tmp_stuff; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

and you can finaly call the `getyourstuff` after that :)

any question , feel free :)